# .Net Remoting functionality

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting

I've recently started with .Net remoting and I have managed to get working with some simple tutorials such as building a library dll that works as a calculator which the client can access and use(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ve4AQnZ-_H0).

What I'm looking for to understand is how I could access current information that is held on the server. For example if I have this simple part running on the server:

```
int x = 0;

while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
{
x++;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

What I found so far is that the dll built is only returning a static result, such as with the calculator. I'd want to be able to tell how much x is on the server at any given time, through the client.

I don't know if I'm being clear enough but I'll try to explain better if it's needed.

Comment: .NET remoting should only be used to work with legacy components, any new development should be done in WCF. (see the bold text at the top of [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.100).ASPX))

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Even WCF is pretty much deprecated and should not be used in new developments, unless you really need SOAP or really certain features enabled only by WCF. Otherwise, use WebAPI. In this case, the calculator could use the server and request x to be incremented. x could be static and the operation could simply return the global value (Although I wouldn't put this in production for obvious concurrency issues).

Comment: @gretro meh, I say WCF and WebAPI co-exist. one is good for some stuff and one is good for other stuff. Neither one replaces the other.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain In term of functionality, I tend to agree with you. However, it's not a coincidence WCF didn't make it into .NET Core. They didn't want it there. But you are right. For certain stuff, I wouldn't use WebAPI (but there are limited cases). In this case however, a WebAPI service would be a much better approach. Less configuration, simpler approach.

Comment: @gretro _"Even WCF is pretty much deprecated and should not be used in new developments"_ - apples and oranges good sir

Comment: @gretro _"it's not a coincidence WCF didn't make it into .NET Core"_ - neither did EF or Rx framework. Are they too "deprecated"?

Comment: @MickyD I tend to disagree. WCF and WebAPI are similar because they both aim at offering a way to create Web Services in .NET. As per .NET Core, the aim was web-related, therefore, anything MS wants to invest in for Web Development (including services) made it to .NET Core in the first version. Comparing WPF and WebAPI is comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @MickyD I see that you edited your comment. EF did make it into .NET Core. Please check EF7. As per Rx, I never had to use it, but it seems to be aimed at observables, which is not really relevant in the MVC pattern and in the Web in general since it's based on Request-Response. An exception to this could be SignalR and Websocket development in general, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: WCF is not deprecated in the slightest way. It's just not (and never was) a good choice for a web-facing service to be consumed by HTML sites. For backend systems web services are very common. WCF is a low prio component to migrate into .NET Core.

Comment: I'm aware that there are newer technologies to use but I am stuck using remoting for this project. Is there a way to solve it through remoting?

Answer (score 1):

In the following Server implementation demonstrates how you can keep state between calls.

```
// this gets instantiated by clients over remoting
public class Server:MarshalByRefObject
{
    // server wide state
    public static int Value;

    // state only for this instance (that can be shared with several clients
    // depending on its activation model)
    private StringBuilder buildup;

    // an instance
    public Server()
    {
        buildup = new StringBuilder();
        Console.WriteLine("server started");
    }

    // do something useful
    public int DoWork(char ch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("server received {0}", ch);
        buildup.Append(ch);
        return Value;
    }

    // return all typed chars
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("server GetMessage called") ;
        return buildup.ToString();
    }

    // how long should this instance live
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        // run forever
        return null;
    }
}
```

Notice the override `InitializeLifetimeService`. If you don't control this, your instance will get torn down after 5 minutes.

To use the above class we use the following code to get a listener up and running, including some of your logic. Don't forget to add an reference to the assembly `System.Runtime.Remoting`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // which port 
    var chn = new HttpChannel(1234);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chn, false);

    // Create only ONE Server instance
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
        typeof(Server), "server", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);

    Server.Value = 0;
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        Server.Value++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(Server.Value);
    }
}
```

When this code runs, it should listen on your local box on port 1234 for connections. On first run I had to disable the firewall, allow that port to pass the local firewall.

A client implementation that uses the `Server` might look like this. Don't forget to add an reference to the assembly `System.Runtime.Remoting`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var chn = new HttpChannel();
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chn, false);

    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(
        typeof(Server),
        "http://localhost:1234/server");

    Console.WriteLine("Creating server...");
    var s = new Server();

    Console.WriteLine("type chars, press p to print, press x to stop");
    var ch = Console.ReadKey();
    while(ch.KeyChar != 'x')
    {

        switch(ch.KeyChar )
        {
            case 'p':
                Console.WriteLine("msg: {0}", s.GetMessage());
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Got value {0} ", s.DoWork(ch.KeyChar));
                break;
        }

            ch = Console.ReadKey();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("stopped");
}
```

If you compile and run this your result can look like this:

[image: demo of client and server with remoting]